# How to import js file in nodejs (in cloud9)

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

This is a basic question, but I'm struggling to find the answer.  I am trying to import a js file (located here: http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/ancestry.js) into my Cloud9 Nodejs IDE, but I don't know how to do it.

I have successfully imported the file into my library.  However, I am unclear on what I am to do with the code added at the bottom of the file:

```
// `require(./path/to/ancestry.js)` will get you the array.
if (typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports)
  module.exports = ANCESTRY_FILE;
```

I tried adding it to the server.js file with no success.

Thanks in advance,
josh

Comment: Did you try saving the file as is and instead call it inside another JS file, within the same directory, using `var ancestry = require('./ancestry');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code at the bottom is usually to check whether [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) is enabled (basically, is it Node.js or browser). As long as you have the ancestry file in a folder, make another file inside the same folder, e.g: `list-ancenstry.js` and write into it:

```
var ancestry = require("./ancestry"); 
console.log(ancestry) //Logs the array
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked.  However, I cannot run the code in the immediate window (Javascript REPL).                                                                                     The following gets me a ReferenceError: var ancestry = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE)

Comment: NO, run it using `require`. Make sure you read up on module imports in Node.js. Btw, whats your setup? It doesn't sound like a generic Node.js setup.

Comment: If I type 'var ancestry = require("./ancestry");' in the immediate window, I get 'ReferenceError: require is not defined'.  As far as my set-up is concerned, I'm afraid I don't know how to answer that question.  This is new to me.  What information are you looking for?

Comment: If `require` is undefined, it looks like your node setup needs some tweaking.